# Get last price before order date

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

In SQL Server, I have a table that contains the price list by date.

`item` table:

```
itemNbr varchar(50),
itemName varchar(100),.......
```

`price_list`:

```
itemNbr varchar(50),
startDate DateTime,
salePrice  decimal(12,2)
```

It could have data like this:

```
item1, 01/01/2023,  2.00
item1, 01/15/2023,  2.50
item1, 02/01/2023,  3.00
item3, 01/01/2023,  1.00
```

I also have an order tables (header and line) with typical columns like

`orderHeader`:

```
id   varchar(50), --unique id guid
orderDate dateTime,
orderNbr  integer,
customerNbr varchar(50)...........
```

`OrderLine`:

```
headerId  varchar(50), --unique id guid
lineNbr integer,
itemNbr varchar(50),
price  decimal(12,2)
qty decimal(12,2), ................
```

When an order is placed, the default `salePrice` is the LAST price defined in the `price_list` table where the `start_Date <= order_date`.

In the example above, if an order was placed on 01/08 the price will be 2.00 but if it is placed after 01/15 but before February then it will be 2.5.

During order entry the operator can enter a price other than the default `salePrice` proposed from the `price_list` table.

I need to run a query that returns for each order/order line the actual price from the order line and the default `salePrice` that was proposed when the order was placed.

I tried the following query but it is not working and returning 0 as `salePrice` always:

```
select
    l.itemNbr, i.itemName, h.orderNbr, h.orderDate, 
    l.Qty, l.price, l.total, sp.salePrice
from
    orderHeader h
join 
    orderLine l on h.id = l.headerId 
join 
    item i on i.itemNbr = l.itemNbr 
left join 
    (select top 1 
         price_list.itemNbr, price_list.salePrice, price_list.startDate
     from 
         price_list
     order by 
         startDate Desc) as sp on sp.itemNbr = l.itemNbr 
                               and sp.startDate <=  h.orderDate;
```

Is there an easy way to this?

Comment: Why do you store a GUID as a `varchar(50)` when there is a dedicated datatype for it?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results - its very hard to work out why a query isn't working without data to work with - hence if you can provide it as DDL+DML you'll get a response much faster..

Comment: You `price_list` sub-query isn't correlated to the `itemNbr` - you need a `where itemNbr = ??`

Comment: Change your `LEFT JOIN` to `OUTER APPLY` and add a `ORDER BY` in the `APPLY` query

Comment: I think this is a bad way of storing prices. They should be frozen on order level and not being fetched repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way (definitely not the only way):

```
;with price_list_w_enddate as (

   select 
        itemNbr ,startDate,
        enddate=lead(dateadd(day, -1, startdate),1,'9999-12-31') over (partition by itemnbr order by startdate),
        salePrice
    from price_list
)
select
    l.itemNbr, h.orderNbr, h.orderDate, 
    l.Qty, l.price, sp.salePrice
from
    orderHeader h
join 
    orderLine l on h.id = l.headerId 
left join 
   price_list_w_enddate sp
   on sp.itemNbr=l.itemNbr
   and h.orderDate between sp.startDate and sp.EndDate
```

In this method I added an endDate to the price_list.

I removed some details from your query to save myself time, because you didn't give us usable data; I trust you can add them back.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it did work and not only that, but you helped me to learn new features in sqlserver.